# Duplicate plugin key: FLTGoogleMapsPlugin

Tags: xcode, google-maps, dart, flutter

I am trying to prepare a demo project using Google maps with flutter but don't know why getting crash with this error in console

> ```
> Runner[39966:208120] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
> 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Duplicate plugin key:
> FLTGoogleMapsPlugin'
> ```

I have followed this link
[flutter-io](https://medium.com/flutter-io/google-maps-and-flutter-cfb330f9a245)

Any help is appreciated thanks in advance.

Comment: Note Google Maps for Flutter is currently in developer preview. This increases the risk of breaking changes.

Comment: `'Duplicate plugin key:` are you using the correct key ?

Comment: @RubensMelo, m not aware of this plugin key. Can you tell me, what it is and where I can find this?

Comment: @TinusJackson, I have read that in the link, which means I can only use Google Maps for flutter in dev mode. Right? Correct me if m wrong.

Comment: @NikunjRajyaguru No, have you tried this https://fireship.io/lessons/flutter-realtime-geolocation-firebase/. Should be similar, also uses a different version of flutter gmaps plugin

Comment: to add a map to your app, you have to get a google api key and configure project with that key: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/google_maps_flutter

Comment: @RubensMelo Yes, I have added the correct google api key.

Comment: @RubensMelo and TinusJackson Well,I got it, was silly mistake that have written a line two times. Thanks a lot guys. :)

Comment: It happened to me, too. I didn't add the duplicate line.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just to clarify the comments and provide a final answer - you should be careful that `[GeneratedPluginRegistrant registerWithRegistry:self]` is not called twice in your AppDelegate.m file.

As per [the Google Maps Flutter plugin readme](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter#getting-started), your AppDelegate.m should look like this:

```
#include "AppDelegate.h"
#include "GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h"
#import "GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
      [GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"YOUR KEY HERE"];
      [GeneratedPluginRegistrant registerWithRegistry:self];
      return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}

@end
```